# extra NULL item in spring-jpa one-to-many list attribute

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

spring-jpa with hibernate and mysql 5.7 (dependency managed by spring platform-bom-1.1.4.RELEASE)

Entity class:

```html
@Entity
@Table(name = "activity")
public class ActivityEntity
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    // optional
    @Column(name="project_id")
    private Integer projectId;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="container_id")
    private ActivityEntity container;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="container", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderColumn(name="order")
    private List<ActivityEntity> activities;
    
    private String name;
    private String description;

...
}
```

DAO class:

```html
public interface IActivityDao extends JpaRepository<ActivityEntity, Integer>
{

    List<ActivityEntity> findByContainerId(int containerId);
    
}
```

Database table:

```html
CREATE TABLE `activity` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `container_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `mode` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `script` longtext,
  `order` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `created_user_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_user_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `projectId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `container_id` (`container_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_container_id` FOREIGN KEY (`container_id`) REFERENCES `activity` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=214 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Database table content:
[image]

Unit Test Code:

```html
public class ActivityDaoTest extends AbstractDaoTest
{
    @Resource
    private IActivityDao activityDao;
    
    @Test
    public void testFindOne() throws Exception {
        ActivityEntity activity = activityDao.findOne(210);
        ActivityEntity root = activity.getContainer();
        
        int level = 0;
        printActivity(activity, level);
        Assert.assertNotNull(activity);
        
        if (root != null) {
            level = 0;
            printActivity(root, level);
        }
    }
...
}
```

In the above test code, root.getActivities() and activity.getActivities() return 5 and 4 items respectively, with the first item to be null.

Do I miss something in the entity? Thanks for help.

Comment: First: the owner side of a OneToMany should be a ManyToOne, not a OneToOne. Second, show your printActivity() method, and show the output.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my won question (posted too early):

1. Remove the *order* attribute from the Entity
2. The value of the *order* column in the table starts from 0 (the NULL item is for the index of 0 in the list)

That solves my problem.

Comment: well no, that simply puts off the problem where you want to order the items of a list via an order column, and find later on that your JPA provider is maybe doing something wrong. I use a different provider, so doesn't bother me, but may bother you at some later point if you don't debug it now